# How to get around EF not liking Lists when using a NoSQL database?

Tags: entity-framework, azure-cosmosdb

I'm working with a CosmosDB, which just stores JSON documents (is my understanding anyhow)

So far it's been fine, I have several collections working. I have one collection now where it will store a list of Guids. EF freaks out about the entity and primary keys, which would make sense in SQL land, as it's a different dynamic and this would notate an actual database relationship.

> The entity type 'List' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'.

But here, I would expect it to simply save off the Guids as strings in a JSON array under that property. There is a key defined, so complaining about the key seems strange. And the suggestion to make it a keyless entity is not desired and also seems... silly.

```
public class OwnerModel {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }    
    public List<Guid> ProductIds { get; set; } = new();
}
```

And in the FluentAPI:

```
builder.Entity<OwnerModel >()
    .ToContainer(nameof(OwnerModel))
    .HasNoDiscriminator()
    .HasKey("Id");
```

I don't have the ProductModel built out or anything yet, but for the way, the front end is going to utilize this data, I only need to return a list of ids for the products here. I don't need/want to store all the product data inside the owner's record.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The entity type 'Access' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type call 'HasNoKey()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60600835/the-entity-type-access-requires-a-primary-key-to-be-defined-if-you-intended-t)

Comment: @Jeppe nope, `HasForiegnKey` doesn't seem to be a property when working within the CosmosDB context. I did try adding the product model and doing the "has many" setup, but no change in the issue

Answer (score 0):

> I only need to return a list of ids for the products here. I don't need/want to store all the product data inside the owner's record.

**Explanation:**

Below Is the explanation and the code which I have written to get list of **productId's**:

- The `Owners` collection is used by the application to read an owner document. The document is retrieved using the owner's ID.
- To get a list of all product IDs, query the `Products` collection.
- The list of product IDs is added to the **ProductIds** field of the Owner class, which updates the retrieved owner record.
- The `ReplaceItemAsync` method is used to replace the outdated owner document in the `Owners` collection.

**Code I tried with:**

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string endpointUrl = "****";
        string primaryKey = "****";
        string databaseId = "newDb";
        string productsCollectionId = "Products";
        string ownersCollectionId = "Owners";
        string ownerId = "1"; // ID of the owner you want to update

        using (CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient(endpointUrl, primaryKey))
        {
            try
            {
                var database = client.GetDatabase(databaseId);
                var productsContainer = database.GetContainer(productsCollectionId);
                var ownersContainer = database.GetContainer(ownersCollectionId);

                // Retrieve the owner document
                var ownerResponse = await ownersContainer.ReadItemAsync<Owner>(ownerId, new PartitionKey(ownerId));
                var owner = ownerResponse.Resource;

                // Retrieve all product IDs from the Products collection
                var productIdsIterator = productsContainer.GetItemQueryIterator<string>(
                    new QueryDefinition("SELECT VALUE c.id FROM c"));

                var productIds = new List<string>();
                while (productIdsIterator.HasMoreResults)
                {
                    var response = await productIdsIterator.ReadNextAsync();
                    productIds.AddRange(response);
                }

                owner.ProductIds = productIds;
                await ownersContainer.ReplaceItemAsync(owner, owner.Id, new PartitionKey(owner.Id));
                Console.WriteLine("All Product IDs added to the owner document.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error occurred: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
```

**Input:**
[image]

**Output:**
[image]

[image]